# Connected components of the complement of a geodesic

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I came across the book "Knots, Molecules, and the Universe: An Introduction to Topology" by E. Flapan which is quite nice. In the first chapters it is discussed how one can distinguish the sphere $S^2$ from the torus $T^2$ in a way that I didn't think about before: you consider the number of connected components of a (closed) geodesic. For example on $S^2$ the closed geodesics are the great circles, so the complement always has two connected components. On the other hand, on the torus there is a closed geodesic whose complement is still connected.

Is there any name for this invariant? Can you define the same also in higher dimensions? In the book the essentially same way is used to distinguish $S^3$ from $T^3$ but you somehow have to "blow-up" your geodesic to something two-dimensional and this process is not so clear to me.